# Does 2.x external chaincode container depends on capabilities or binaries?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was following the link for upgrade components https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/upgrading_your_components.html. Currently I am running 1.4.1 network, and if I upgrade my binaries to 2.2, and put the capabilities as is (1.4), will it possible to run external chaincode container or chaincode as a service with 1.4 capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You run images and binary 1.4 along the capabilities 1.4, actually your chaincodes are launched by the peer and then connect to peer. So it's a 2.0 feature and u should run with capability 2.0.